# Count occurrences of a given integer in an array using recursion

Tags: java, recursion

Without using a loop, I'm trying to count the number of times a given integer is in an array using recursion. I keep getting a StackOverflow error and I can't figure out why.

```
public static int countOccurrences(int[] arr, int n) {
    if (arr.length == 0) {
        return 0;
    }
    if (arr[0] == n) {
        return 1 + countOccurrences(arr, n - 1);
    }
    return countOccurrences(arr, n - 1);
}
```

}

Comment: It's due to n-1 ...you are not ending the recursion

Comment: You are changing the search value and passing it on next call

Comment: When you make the recursive call, you need to make the array smaller somehow.  Instead of doing that, you're changing the number that you're searching for, but searching in the same array.  Since you're never making the array smaller, your recursion will never reach the base case.

Comment: @ChengThao that is both unhelpful and untrue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can use only two parameters, then try:

```
    public static int countOccurrences(int[] arr, int n) {
        if (arr.length == 0) {
            return 0;
        }
        if (arr[0] == n) {
            return 1 + countOccurrences(Arrays.copyOfRange(arr, 1, arr.length), n);
        }
        return countOccurrences(Arrays.copyOfRange(arr, 1, arr.length), n);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

the problem with above code is that the base condition will never be satisfied as you are never trying to reduce the length of the array. To keep track of length traversed, you can use a variable that starts from end to start ( or from start to end your choice ) . And let's say , num is the value that you want to count. Then you can change your code to like this :

```
public class CountFrequency {
        
                public static void main(String[] args) {
                    int A[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5 };
                    int count = countOccurences(A, 5);
                    System.out.println(count);
                }
            
                private static int countOccurences(int[] arr, int num) {
                    return helper(arr, num, arr.length - 1);
            
                }
            
                private static int helper(int[] arr, int num, int i) {
                    if (i == -1) {
                        return 0;
                    }
                    if (arr[i] == num)
                        return 1 + helper(arr, num, i - 1);
                    else
                        return helper(arr, num, i - 1);
                }
      }
```

and the output is

```
2
```

Comment: the problem is i can only use two parameters the array and the number we're looking for

Comment: I can use a helper function

Comment: is there a way i could use that as a helper function

Comment: @carriebrown i have edited my code, i hope this will help

Comment: ```i==0``` should be ```i==-1```.  You want to include the element at index 0.

Comment: @ChengThao, yes, you are right :)